# First item in collection doesn't submit the action [EDITED]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have two controllers which modify one big view (carts/new.html.erb). This view render order_item/new.html.erb passing each product of @products as a result of a search. This function works fine. But when I click the submit button of the form created for each product this doesn't work (ONLY FOR THE FIRST PRODUCT), for the others products it works fine. So, I see the generated html and the first form tag is not generated.

Missing tag

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/order_items" class="new_order_item" data-remote="true" id="new_order_item" method="post"></form>
```

Thanks!

Carts/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Ordenes</h1>
<%= form_tag orders_path, :method => 'get', :id => "products_search" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Buscar", :name => nil %>
  </p>
  <div id="products">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Precio Compra</th>
        <th>Precio Venta</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <%= will_paginate @products%>


<div id="found_products"><%= render 'found_products' %></div>
          <% end %> 
    </table>
  </div>
<% end %>
<div>
  <h2>Orden actual</h2>
  <div id="shopping_cart">
    <%= render "shopping_cart", :locals => { :order_items => @order_items }%>
  </div>
```

Carts/_found_products.html.erb

```
 <% @products.each do |product| %>
<%= render template: "order_items/new", :locals => { :product => product } %>
<% end %>
```

Order_items/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for OrderItem.new, :url => { :action => "create",:controller=>"order_items" }, method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>

<tr>

 <td><%= product.code %></td>

 <td><%= product.name %></td>

 <td><%= product.buy_price %></td>

 <td><%= product.sell_price %></td>



 <td><%= f.number_field :quantity, class: "form-control width: 50%", min: 0 %></td>

 <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>

 <td><%= f.submit "Agregar a la orden", class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>



</tr>

<% end %>
```

Order_items/create.js.erb

```
$("#shopping_cart").html("<%=escape_javascript(render partial: 'carts/shopping_cart', locals: { order_items: @order_items, order: @order } ) %>");
```

Order_items_controller.erb

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user
  def new
  @order = current_order
  @order_item = @order.order_items.new
  end


  def create

    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)




    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html {redirect_to orders_path, notice: "Item ingresado"}
        format.js {}
        session[:order_id] = @order.id
        #format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to orders_path, notice: "Error #{@order.errors}" }
        #format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end


  end

  def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items

     respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html {redirect_to orders_path, notice: "Item modificado"}
        format.js {}

        #format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to orders_path, notice: "Error #{@order.errors}" }
        #format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end
  private
    def order_item_params
      params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id)
    end
    def signed_in_user
        unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Por favor, ingrese sus credenciales" 
    end
  end
end
```

Carts_controller.erb

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user

    def new
        @products = Product.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
        @order_items=current_order.order_items

    end

private

  def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Por favor, ingrese sus credenciales" 
  end
end

end
```

Log when I click the first product button. [EDITED]

```
Started GET "/orders?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=5DtAkn%2F7Ec2pjlbRH7ndQhmBVvY3l3FaFtxVxyalZSQ%3D&order_item%5Bquantity%5D=2&order_item%5Bproduct_id%5D=1&commit=Agregar+a+la+orden" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-15 23:32:52 -0300

Processing by CartsController#new as HTML

  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"", "authenticity_token"=>"5DtAkn/7Ec2pjlbRH7ndQhmBVvY3l3FaFtxVxyalZSQ=", "order_item"=>{"quantity"=>"2", "product_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Agregar a la orden"}

  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'fyF-zqLjJHV7xzC3nnVdPQ' LIMIT 1[0m

  [1m[35mOrder Load (8.3ms)[0m  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 63]]

  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 63]]

  [1m[35mProduct Load (0.7ms)[0m  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (name LIKE '%%') LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0

  [1m[36m (0.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE (name LIKE '%%')[0m

  Rendered order_items/new.html.erb (46.4ms)

  Rendered order_items/new.html.erb (4.4ms)

  Rendered order_items/new.html.erb (2.7ms)

  Rendered order_items/new.html.erb (2.6ms)

  Rendered order_items/new.html.erb (3.5ms)

  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = 63

  [1m[36mOrderItem Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = 63[0m

  [1m[35mProduct Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1

  Rendered carts/_cart_row.html.erb (8.4ms)

  [1m[36mProduct Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1[0m

  Rendered carts/_cart_row.html.erb (5.8ms)

  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = 63

  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1[0m

  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1

  Rendered carts/_shopping_cart.html.erb (65.0ms)

  Rendered carts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (184.3ms)

  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (6.9ms)

  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)

Completed 200 OK in 792ms (Views: 590.6ms | ActiveRecord: 22.3ms)
```

Log when I click other product

```
Started POST "/order_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-10 02:21:22 -0300
Processing by OrderItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7pM8PRU8Uy4euEtSv/GZyHjRPewdIiAzXDp5xQnd9u0=", "order_item"=>{"quantity"=>"7", "product_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Agregar a la orden"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'DUoiwJ5FkXlFIXty3UE8xA' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mOrder Load (8.8ms)[0m  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 34]]
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mProduct Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (4.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "order_items" ("created_at", "order_id", "product_id", "quantity", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", Tue, 10 Mar 2015 05:21:23 UTC +00:00], ["order_id", 34], ["product_id", 3], ["quantity", 7], ["updated_at", Tue, 10 Mar 2015 05:21:23 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (71.2ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/orders
Completed 302 Found in 378ms (ActiveRecord: 95.0ms)


Started GET "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-10 02:21:23 -0300
Processing by CartsController#new as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'DUoiwJ5FkXlFIXty3UE8xA' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mOrder Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 34]]
  [1m[36mProduct Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "products".* FROM "products" LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0[0m
  Rendered order_items/new.html.erb (8.6ms)
  Rendered order_items/new.html.erb (3.9ms)
  Rendered order_items/new.html.erb (3.6ms)
  [1m[35m (0.6ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = 34
  [1m[36mOrderItem Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = 34[0m
  [1m[35mProduct Load (0.6ms)[0m  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  Rendered carts/_cart_row.html.erb (6.8ms)
  Rendered carts/_shopping_cart.html.erb (20.4ms)
  Rendered carts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (74.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (6.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 378ms (Views: 366.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

Comment: Your logs are showing two very different actions. The breaking one has nothing to do with submitting your order_items form - it is to do with creating a new cart. `CartsController#new` and it's breaking because you haven't passed `product` as a variable into Carts/new.js.erb - how is the order-items controller going ot the carts controller?

Comment: Ok, What can I do? I don't understand how is this working in the other products.

Comment: The problem (as is clear in the logs) is that there is no variable called `product` set up in your `CartsController#new` action - and yet the template `app/views/carts/new.js.erb` (which will be rendered by that action) clearly expects there to be a `product` variable. I don't know how and when you expect this action to be called... but that's your problem - now you have to figure out whether you need to set up that variable, or change the template to do something else instead.

Comment: I understand that new.js.erb isn't doing nothing. So I removed that file. Now, when I click the first product the logs show only the second action without errors:

Started GET "/orders?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=7pM8PRU8Uy4euEtSv%2FGZyHjRPewdIiAzXDp5xQnd9u0%3D&order_item%5Bquantity%5D=3&order_item%5Bproduct_id%5D=2&commit=Agregar+a+la+orden" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-10 02:19:29 -0300
Processing by CartsController#new as HTML

Comment: 1) code-formatting in comments is awful = please put all code into your original question 2) that looks like just the *starting* line of the stacktrace... the rest is important too.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is the first time I use this forum

Comment: That's ok, that's why i let you know :)

Comment: So... we're still trying to figure out why we're getting a  `CartsController#new` action instead of `ProductsController#new` I can't tell you that - you have to find out why your code is doing that. How are these two controllers related? what is calling CartsController?